# How to capture values from panel placed on a form

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am not understanding how to capture values in a text box placed in a panel on a form. I am trying to update my database table with these values.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Code:**

```
private void btnSupplier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Panel pnlAddSupplier = new Panel();
            TextBox txtSupplierID = new TextBox();
            TextBox txtSupplierName = new TextBox();
            Button btnAddSupplier = new Button();
            Label lblSupplierID = new Label();
            Label lblSupplierName = new Label();

            // Initialize the Panel control.
            pnlAddSupplier.Location = new Point(56, 74);
            pnlAddSupplier.Size = new Size(200, 200);
            // Set the Borderstyle for the Panel to three-dimensional.
            pnlAddSupplier.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;

            // Initialize the Label and TextBox controls.
            lblSupplierID.Location = new Point(60, 0);
            lblSupplierID.Text = "Supplier ID";
            lblSupplierID.Size = new Size(104, 20);
            txtSupplierID.Location = new Point(20, 40);
            txtSupplierID.Text = "";
            txtSupplierID.Size = new Size(152, 20);

            lblSupplierName.Location = new Point(20, 70);
            lblSupplierName.Text = "Supplier Name";
            lblSupplierName.Size = new Size(150, 20);
            txtSupplierName.Location = new Point(20, 90);
            txtSupplierName.Text = "";
            txtSupplierName.Size = new Size(152, 20);

            lblSupplierID.Location = new Point(16, 16);
            lblSupplierID.Text = "Supplier ID";


            btnAddSupplier.Location = new Point(60, 120);
            btnAddSupplier.Text = "Add";
            btnAddSupplier.Click += btnAddSupplier_Click;
            // Add the Panel control to the form. 
            this.Controls.Add(pnlAddSupplier);
            // Add the Label and TextBox controls to the Panel.
            pnlAddSupplier.Controls.Add(lblSupplierID);
            pnlAddSupplier.Controls.Add(txtSupplierID);
            pnlAddSupplier.Controls.Add(lblSupplierName);
            pnlAddSupplier.Controls.Add(txtSupplierName);
            pnlAddSupplier.Controls.Add(btnAddSupplier);

        }
        catch { }
    }

 public void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username= //how to assign textbox value?;
            int age = //how to assign textbox value;

            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();

            string query = "INSERT INTO table(username, age) VALUES ('@xxx', '@xxx') "; 

             //please not these values are for demonstration.

            using (connection)
            {
                  ObjDb.OpenConnection();
                ObjDb.ExecuteNonQuery(query, connection);
            }
        }
```

As you can see this code is open to SQL injection, and I want to use parameters. In order to do so I need to capture the details input. How can this be achieved?

I have tried to assign the `supplierID = txtSupplierID.Text` but I get a message saying `txtSupplier.Text` does not exist.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which textbox is used for the age, but I hope this gives you a good start point.

```
string username = txtSupplierID.Text; // how to assign textbox value?;
int age = Int32.Parse(...); // how to assign textbox value;
```

You need more validation on age. Therefore, it is better to use:

```
int age;
if (!Int32.TryParse(..., out age))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect age!");
    return;
}
```

Change txtSupplierID to a field:

```
private TextBox txtSupplierName;
```

And update these line:

```
txtSupplierName = new TextBox(); // remove TextBox
```

Comment: I have already this tried, I can't seem to access this textbox. I get "txtSupplierID.Text" does not exist. Also the values are just for demonstration I am not actually storing age value. But good to point out validations.

Comment: In that case, make the `txtSupplierID` a field instead of a local variable.

Comment: I have declared this before creating the panel.  TextBox txtSupplierID = new TextBox();

Comment: If you declare it earlier, it is still a local variable. When your `btnSupplier_Click` ends, the local variable is out of scope. Therefore, you should make it a field.

Comment: I see, so if I do make it a field. Would that not affect the txtSupplierID.Location = new Point(20,40)? I am sure will throw an null reference error.

Comment: When the control is created earlier than referencing it, I don't expect a null reference error. Therefore, `txtSupplierName = new TextBox();` but be called earlier than `txtSupplierID.Location = new Point(20,40);`. And that is the case.

Comment: thanks, sorry silly mistake. Although I created a field I did not create a new instance. I had to do txtSupplierID = new TextBox(); before like you said.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you meant? Assuming user will always enter number of integer value in txtSupplierID TextBox this should work just fine. Assign Name property to your Control and reach for it by that Name. Feel free to ask anything I left unexplained. Cheers!

```
private void btnSupplier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel pnlAddSupplier = new Panel()
    {
        Name = "pnlAddSupplier",
        Location = new Point(56, 74),
        Size = new Size(200, 200),
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
    };
    TextBox txtSupplierID = new TextBox()
    {
        Name = "txtSupplierID",
        Location = new Point(20, 40),
        Text = string.Empty,
        Size = new Size(152, 20)
    };
    TextBox txtSupplierName = new TextBox()
    {
        Name = "txtSupplierName",
        Location = new Point(20, 90),
        Text = string.Empty,
        Size = new Size(152, 20)
    };
    Label lblSupplierID = new Label()
    {
        Name = "lblSupplierID",
        Location = new Point(20, 20),
        Text = "Supplier ID:",
        Size = new Size(104, 20)
    };
    Label lblSupplierName = new Label()
    {
        Name = "lblSupplierName",
        Location = new Point(20, 70),
        Text = "Supplier Name:",
        Size = new Size(150, 20)
    };
    Button btnAddSupplier = new Button()
    {
        Name = "btnAddSupplier",
        Location = new Point(60, 120),
        Text = "Add",
    };
    btnAddSupplier.Click += btnAdd_Click;

    // Add controls to the Panel.
    pnlAddSupplier.Controls.Add(lblSupplierID);
    pnlAddSupplier.Controls.Add(txtSupplierID);
    pnlAddSupplier.Controls.Add(lblSupplierName);
    pnlAddSupplier.Controls.Add(txtSupplierName);
    pnlAddSupplier.Controls.Add(btnAddSupplier);

    // Add the Panel control to the form. 
    this.Controls.Add(pnlAddSupplier);
}

public void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = this.Controls["pnlAddSupplier"].Controls["txtSupplierName"].Text;
    int age = Int32.Parse(this.Controls["pnlAddSupplier"].Controls["txtSupplierID"].Text);

    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();

    string query = "INSERT INTO table(username, age) VALUES ('@xxx', '@xxx') ";

    using (connection)
    {
        ObjDb.OpenConnection();
        ObjDb.ExecuteNonQuery(query, connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a null reference exception on string username =  this.Controls["pnlAddSupplier"].Controls["txtSupplierName"].Text;

Comment: @Harry I just tried it and it works fine. You have to assign Name property of the control. txtSupplierName.Name = "txtSupplierName"; Are you sure you did that?

Answer (score 0):

You are making your supplier ID textbox a local variable to your btnSupplier_Click function.  You need to make it a class variable.  Then this variable should present be in your *.designer.cs file if you use the designer to drag and drop it onto your web page.

Here is how you can use parameters to prevent SQL injection:

```
            DbCommand myCommand = Connection.CreateCommand();
            myCommand.CommandText = @"select * from myTable mt
                where 
                mt.paramter = @myParameter";

            DbParameter myParameter = myCommand.CreateParameter();
            myParameter.ParameterName = "@myParameter";
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(myParameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to name the controls:

```
 txtSupplierID.Name = "txtSupplierID";
```

Then you can get the value like this:

```
Control[] Found = this.Controls.Find("txtSupplierID", true);

TextBox IDTextBox = Found[0] as TextBox;

string SupplierID = IDTextBox.Text;
```

Don't forget to add error checking!

Comment: `Control ctrl = Controls["txtSupplierID"];` could be used as well to locate the control.